# Connecting ButtonArray to XML buttons

Tags: java, android, arrays, button, android-studio

first thank for any help.
im creating an a Calculator application,
in the XML file, i Created the buttons [0-9]
and now im tring to put them all in Button Array

```
 int NumberOfButtons=10;

Button button[] = new Button[NumberOfButtons];
```

this is the array,
before trying to use the array, i created every button

```
 Button one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, zero, add, sub, mul, div, cancel,
        equal;
```

now this is the buttons that connects by findValueid

```
 one = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    two = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    three = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    four = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    five = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    six = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    seven = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
    eight = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
    nine = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);
    zero = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button0);
```

how can i save processing power, and using less code?
like FOR function
or maybe using While

thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) to make it.That will be less code and more readable.

Comment: The task requires Buttons   :(

Comment: I know.Every gridView's item will be a button,like button1,button2...etc.

Answer (score 1):

You code is already very simple and will execute quickly. Typically each button will need written as you have done - which makes calculators a pain to write code for. The use of loops, in this case, I don't think applies - not to make it more efficient.

Now you need to figure out where your onTouch() event is in order to place and detect touch events for your buttons.

What @FireSun suggested is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
int[] ids = {
    R.id.button1
    , R.id.button2
    , R.id.button3
    ...
    , R.id.button9
}

for (int id : ids) {
    findViewById(id).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

if your id of buttons have rules, try this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) {
    String buttonId = "button" + i;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(buttonId, "id", getPackageName());
    findViewById(resourceId).setOnClickListener(this);
}
```